# Difference between SBT compile vs compileIncremental

Tags: scala, build, compilation, sbt

What is conceptual difference between compile and compileIncremental in sbt OR how things work differently under the hood in both the cases.

Comment: http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Understanding-Recompilation.html#Implementation+of+incremental+recompilation

Answer (score 2):

As documented in [Running](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Running.html), please use `compile` to compile your code.

If you are curious about what's going on under the hood, you can take a look at https://github.com/sbt/sbt/pull/1714 and the corresponding part in [Defaults.scala](https://github.com/sbt/sbt/blob/v1.0.0-RC3/main/src/main/scala/sbt/Defaults.scala#L1360-L1395). In short `compileIncremental` is an internal task that is set up so plugins can intercept and manipulate the bytecode before caching occurs.